# "Can't open PivotTable source file '[myfilename.xlsx#BgEIDA4ADAMGBAcBBAQECw=1182.0]Master'

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I run a query from copy/paste its results into a Sheet in an Excel file.  When I go Data > Refresh All, I get the error below multiple times:
[image: Excel Pivot Table Error]

The `'[MS Master.FY22.xls.....]Master` does not contain a pivot table. However, the Excel file has several pivot tables in various other Sheets which pull data from the 'Master' Sheet.

I have gone Sheet by Sheet and under the PivotTable Analyze > Change Data Source to repoint to the `'Master'` file. This fixed it from receiving the error multiple times and instead it just appears once now. I think there may be an overlapping pivot table that may be the culprit. I really do not want to delete and recreate all the pivot tables.

Is there a way to find out which Sheet this is happening in and where exactly? Maybe with VB code?

Please let me know if you have any insight on this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Instead of Data > Refresh All, you can right-click on each pivot table and just Refresh (not Refresh All).

Comment: It was unclear from my post, but I have done that already @kevin. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Give this macro a try, it will go through all pivot tables in your workbook and try to refresh them; it should error out on whatever pivot table is giving you the problem, and the sheet name and pivot table name should be written in the immediate window.

```
Sub list_pt()

Dim ws As Worksheet, pt As PivotTable

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        Debug.Print ws.Name, pt.Name, "Attempt Refresh"
        pt.PivotCache.Refresh
        Debug.Print ws.Name, pt.Name, "Refresh Success"
    Next pt
Next ws

End Sub
```